# My Array is out of bounds, but its set higher than the value im calling from it

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class hw16 {

   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MonthlyRecord MonthRecord = new MonthlyRecord("January", 31);
        MonthRecord.Transaction(5, 600);
    
    }
    
}

    
public class MonthlyRecord {

    private String month;
    private int day;
    private double[] moneyDaily = new double[day];

    public MonthlyRecord() {
        this.month = "January";
        this.day = 0;
        this.moneyDaily[1] = 0;
    }

    public MonthlyRecord(String name, int day) {
       
        System.out.println("Hello");
        this.setMonthlyRecord(name);
        this.setDays(day);
    }

    public void setDays(int temp) {
        this.day = temp;
    }

    public void setMonthlyRecord(String temp) {
        this.month = temp;
    }

    public int setDays() {
        return this.day;
    }

    public String getMonthlyRecord() {
        return this.month;
    }

    public void Transaction(int daynum, int amount) {
        System.out.println("You've made $" + amount + " on the " + daynum + "th day");
        System.out.println(moneyDaily[daynum]);

    }

}
```

I'm getting an error:

> Hello You've made $600 on the 5th day Exception in thread "main"
> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5   at
> hwk16jzuramski1.MonthlyRecord.Transaction(MonthlyRecord.java:40)  at
> hwk16jzuramski1.Hwk16jzuramski1.main(Hwk16jzuramski1.java:11) Java
> Result: 1

SO it say's my array is out of bounds which I don't understand? If I'm setting day to the length of my array why is it saying its out of bounds at int 5 when the array length should be 31?

Comment: Looks to me like your array has a size of 0...

Comment: But I set the array length=day and in the main set day to 31 so shouldnt it be 31? or is that not how you would set up the length?

Comment: `moneyDaily` is created with size 0 before your constructor is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think is happening is that at the top of your class your are instantiating the array `monthDaily[]` outside of the constructor. Since the int variable `day` only gets initialized in the constructors you should also instantiate the `monthDaily[]` variable in the constructor. Hence the beginning part of your code would look like:

```
public class MonthlyRecord {

    private String month;
    private int day;
    private double[] moneyDaily;

    public MonthlyRecord() {
        this.month = "January";
        this.day = 0;
        this.moneyDaily = new double[1]; //variable is instantiated to have one slot as default
    }

    public MonthlyRecord(String name, int day) {

        System.out.println("Hello");
        this.setMonthlyRecord(name);
        this.setDays(day);
        moneyDaily = new double[days]; //array gets instantiated with number of slots equal to the value of the day variable
    }
```

Comment: Even after the variable `moneyDaily' gets instantiated it only has zero values in it. Consider passing a double array, full of information, to the constructor and correspondingly initialize that array to have actual values that you may utilize in your code further on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the size of the array upon calling the constructor:

```
public MonthlyRecord(String name, int day) {
    moneyDaily = new double[day];
    System.out.println("Hello");
    this.setMonthlyRecord(name);
    this.setDays(day);
}
```

Otherwise, your array `moneyDaily` will have the size of what day was originally, which is 0.

Comment: So how would I get the array to be the same length as my variable day?

Comment: The list length is still set to 0 thats my problem :/  So my list length isn't equal to day so even daynum -1 still is out of bounds

Comment: ya, that's because you are never resetting the size of `moneyDaily` array after you first initialize it to a size of `day` (which is 0 at first).